# How to change the auto-generated "Discriminator" column in EntityFramework?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am working on some code that makes use of single table inheritance via EF4.3.

There is an entity called User and another entity called Admin. Admin inherits from user.

**User class**

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Username {get;set;}
}
```

**Admin class**

```
public class Admin : User { }
```

EF generated the database tables with a `Discriminator` column. When an `Admin` record is added then `Discriminator="Admin"` and a User record would have `Discriminator="User"`.

My question is, how do I update the `Discriminator` column if I want to make a `User` into and `Admin`?

I tried casting from one object type to the other and saving using EF. but that doesn't change the Discriminator column. How do I change it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Objects can't change their types, ever. If you intend to change the "administrator" setting for a user (reasonable), you should do that with an attribute/property, not a type name.

For example, you could have an association between a `User` object and an `Administrator` object, rather than wanting to *replace* the `User` object with an `Administrator` subtype.

[I wrote about this idea in an old blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304214634/http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2008/07/17/37825/):

> One of the mental barriers that you have to get over when designing a good object relational mapping is the tendency to think primarily in object oriented terms, or relational terms, whichever suits your personality.  A good object relational mapping, though, incorporates both a good object model and a good relational model. For example, let’s say you have a database with a table for People, and related tables for Employees and Customers.  A single person might have a record in all three tables.  Now, from a strictly relational point of view, you could construct a database VIEW for employees and another one for customers, both of which incorporate information from the People table.  When using a one VIEW or the other, you can temporarily think of an individual person as "just" an Employee or "just" a Customer, even though you know that they are both. So someone coming from this worldview might be tempted to do an OO mapping where Employee and Customer are both (direct) subclasses of Person.  But this doesn’t work with the data we have; since a single person has both employee and customer records (and since no Person instance can be of the concrete subtype Employee and Customer simultaneously), the OO relationship between Person and Employee needs to be composition rather than inheritance, and similarly for Person and Customer.

To answer your question directly, there's no way to change this column using EF. You could of course, do it in straight SQL. But for the reason given above, I'd encourage you to change this design.

Comment: This may require some in-depth refactoring of the application I'm working on.

Comment: "Objects can't change their types, ever." - But they can be cast to another type.

Comment: Casting doesn't change types. It either creates a new instance (e.g., with an explicit conversion) or treats the reference as a more specific type. None of this changes the discriminator value.

Comment: @quakkels: *This may require some in-depth refactoring of the application I'm working on* Unfortunately this usually happens if you incorrectly understand requirements for your application and use wrong design. Abusing inheritance is one of the worst thing people can do in their application because fixing such design error in later stages of development is always expensive.

Comment: The first thing comes to my mind is to replace the existing user with a _new_ admin with the same data: `User user = GetUser(); Admin admin = Admin.FromUser(user); dbContext.Users.Remove(user); dbContext.Admins.Add(admin);`. Is there a reason something like this would be a bad idea?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed It's not a _bad_ idea if your system is built from the outset to accommodate the notion that a "Person" record can change over time. But if you have 1000 foreign keys to that person elsewhere in the DB, simply replacing the record could be challenging. So it depends on your design. I would probably model your example as a Person with an associated history of roles.

Comment: "Objects can't change their types, ever." they can, if you provide the missing data to upcast