# deleting row from dreived table without deleting it from the base table using entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

i am a new in entity framework .. i am coding a small project for attendance , i have a base table employee derived from it a contractEmployee table and dailypaidEmployee table .

```
   public class Employee
{
    [Column(Order=1)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 4)]
    public DateTime HiringDate { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 5)]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 6)]
    public int PositionID { get; set; }
}





  public class ContractEmployee : Employee
{
    [Column(Order = 7)]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 8)]
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}

   public class DailyPaidEmployee : Employee
    {
        [Column(Order = 9)]
        public int DailyPaidAmount { get; set; }

    }



public class AttendanceManagementDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public AttendanceManagementDBContext()
            : base("name=AttendanceManagementDBContext")
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }

       public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }



       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("Employee");
           modelBuilder.Entity<ContractEmployee>().ToTable("ContractEmployee");
           modelBuilder.Entity<DailyPaidEmployee>().ToTable("DailyPaiedEmployee");
           base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
       }
    }
 public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork 
    {
        private readonly AttendanceManagementDBContext _Context;

        public UnitOfWork(AttendanceManagementDBContext Context)
        {
            _Context = Context;

            Employees = new EmployeeRepository(Context);


        }

        public IEmployeeRepository Employees { get; private set; }


        public int Complete()
        {
            return _Context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
 void InsertingNewContractEmployee()
        {
            UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(new AttendanceManagementDBContext());
            ContractEmployee ce = new ContractEmployee();
            ce.EmpName = txtEmpName.Text;
            ce.Mobile = txtMobile.Text;
            ce.HiringDate = DateTime.Parse(dtHiringDate.Value.ToShortDateString());
            ce.DepartmentID = (int)cbDepartments.SelectedValue;
            ce.PositionID = (int)cbPositions.SelectedValue;
            ce.Code = txtCode.Text;
            ce.Grade = txtGrade.Text;

            uow.Employees.Add(ce);
            uow.Complete();
        }
        void InsertingNewDailyPaidEmployee()
        {
            UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(new AttendanceManagementDBContext());
            DailyPaidEmployee dpe = new DailyPaidEmployee();
            dpe.EmpName = txtEmpName.Text;
            dpe.Mobile = txtMobile.Text;
            dpe.HiringDate = DateTime.Parse(dtHiringDate.Value.ToShortDateString());
            dpe.DepartmentID = (int)cbDepartments.SelectedValue;
            dpe.PositionID = (int)cbPositions.SelectedValue;
            dpe.DailyPaidAmount = int.Parse(txtDailyPaid.Text);

            uow.Employees.Add(dpe);
            uow.Complete();
        }
```

i making the addition and the update process with successful way , my problem is when i want to move a dailypaidEmployee to ContractEmployee , i don't know how to make it. i try to remove the employee from the dailypaidemployee it doesn't work , so what can i do .

Comment: where are your ContractEmployee and DailyPaidEmployee ib Contest class ?

Comment: also can you show your code where you are able to add records to DailyPaidEmployee  .

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Describe what you tried and how it failed.

Comment: if i want to update a dailypaidEmployee to a contractEmployee  i Can't Delete his Details in the DailyPaidEmployee Only without Deleteing it's Details in the base Class (Employee Table ) and add it in the Contract Table

Answer (score 1):

[You can't change types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10728240/861716). Period.

Of course, *technically* you can. Even in the typed environment of C# you can.  For example, you can change (sort of) an integer into a decimal. That's called *conversion*. The reverse, conversion from decimal to integer, however, can serve as a small demonstration of problems you may encounter when converting your types: decimals don't fit. They may be too large, or they will loose their precision (the conversion isn't lossless).

Likewise, you *could* convert a `DailyPaidEmployee` into a `ContractPaidEmployee` by changing its discriminator value by a simple SQL statement (not EF) and reread the entities from the database (EF). But you'll end up having a database record representing a `ContractEmployee` but having a `DailyPaidAmount` value.

Even if the application wouldn't notice that -- EF won't read the value -- it may pose unexpected problems later. Such problems always come when you're particularly *not* waiting for them.

**Bottom line is: when entities may change "types", even when not frequently, don't use inheritance.** Rather, consider the type to be a *status*: a `DailyPaidEmployee` can be *promoted* (not *converted*) into a `ContractPaidEmployee`, simply by flipping a status flag.

As for the details: move them to separate tables. `Employee` will be the stable data point. It may or may not have data in something like a `DailyPayment` table, or a `Contract` table. When an employee's status changes, you may add its first `Contract`, maybe remove its `DailyPayment` data.

Differences in *behavior* (usually the primary reason for using inheritance and polymorphism) can be modeled by other behavioral patterns, for instance [Strategy](http://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern).

Comment: So what can be done with the right way in this problem.the last thing I figured to delete the employee I want to update and reinsert it with the updated detailes  as new , is this good idea ?

Comment: No, you keep thinking in this conversion frame. It's always beneficial to stay as close to reality as possible. The employee doesn't change at all. After getting contracted it's still the same person, so leave it there. Just change some other details referring to the employee's details. If that doesn't convince you, also *technically* it may be challenging to replace an existing record and keep all referential integrity intact.